# VMware ESXi 6.0 DirectPath I/O PCIe Device Not Working

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I'm attempting to attach a NIC to a specific VM on my basic ESXi 6.0 setup. DirectPath I/O should allow me to do this, and the machine I'm running ESXi on does support VT-d (Dell Optiplex 990 with an i5-2400 CPU).

I can go into vSphere and access the Configuration -> Hardware Advanced Settings area and add the NIC in. Here's a screenshot: [image]

It says that the changes won't take effect until the host is restarted. I've restarted the host many times yet the status won't change and the little orange arrow won't disappear - meaning the device isn't available for the VM to access.

Anyone have any clues as to why it remains in this state?

Comment: Just curious. Why are you doing NIC passthrough?

Comment: How did you proceed in order to restart the host?

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt right clicked the host in the sidebar and selected reboot

Answer (score 0):

The word "host" in the message "Changes made to some of the devices below will not take effect until the host is restarted" refers to the VMware host, ie. the server on which VMware ESXi is installed and running. In other words, it is not sufficient to restart the VM to which you want to attach the NIC. You need to restart the entire VMware server.

Comment: I have restarted the ESXi server, not the virtual machine :)